# yui3 widget error "this.constructor.NAME is undefined"

Tags: javascript, yui, yql, yui3

I am creating a yui3 widget and I keep getting this error: `this.constructor.NAME is undefined`.

I am defining a name in my widget:

```
YUI().add('paginator', function(Y) {

    function Paginate(config) {
        Paginate.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    Paginate.NAME = "paginate";
    ...
```

So, I am not sure what's going on.

Edit:
I also wanted to add that I have just tried to add the default widget skeleton from [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/widget/assets/mywidget.js.txt) and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried running this using FireBug to know exactly at which line it breaks?

Comment: Yeah, it breaks in the yui3 js for 'widget-base' not my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought I would answer this myself in case anyone else comes across this problem.  I forgot the `new` keyword when creating my widget.